# Rewrite GET request into different format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, get, request

I have a search form that is taking a parameter and posting a GET request to an external URL.

```
  .form-group.form-group-sm
    %form{"accept-charset" => "UTF-8", :action => "http://example.com/search/node", :method => "get"}
      %input.form-control{name: 'search_query', placeholder: "Search site...", :type => "text"}
      %button{name: nil}
        %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-search
```

The issue is that the external site needs the GET request to come in this format:

http://example.com/search/node/banana%20%orange

but the written form generates this URL:

http://example.com/search/node/?search_query=banana+orange

Can anyone share any tips on how I can alter the GET request so it is formatted into a proper URL? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make a request to an internal url, then redirect to the external url through a local controller#action.  This is also good for tracking the searches.

Create example_controller.  Add a 'search' action.  Handle the params parsing and redirect.  Add example#search to your routes file.

Sites like Linkedin, Yelp, Google will do this for all external links.

Some code to help

```
# app/controllers/yahoo_controller.rb
class YahooController < ApplicationController

  def search
    redirect_to escaped_url(:p => params[:q])
  end

  private

  def escaped_url(params = {})
    uri = URI('https://search.yahoo.com/search')
    uri.query = params.to_query
    uri.to_s
  end

end
```

and routes

```
get :yahoo_search, :to => 'yahoo#search'
```

and the view

```
= form_tag(yahoo_search_path, :method => :get) do
  = text_field_tag :q, params[:q]
  = submit_tag "Search", :name => nil
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a JS function that will be called on form submission. In that function you can append the params to the GET URL in the format you want and then make the GET request.